# C# Events compared to WCF/SOA Pub-Sub services: Protecting objects from their subscribers

Tags: c#, events, soa, publish-subscribe

Having done alot of WCF services and SOA development over the last 2.5 years including building per-call publish-subscribe services where one of the key principals is that developers should strive to build pure client-server relationships where both clients are ignorant of the internals of a service...they should only know the interface and services should have no dependancies on or details specific to individual clients, it made me think of how this applies to C#'s own publish-subscriber system: event handlers. Really this question applies to any comparable language though.

As I see it objects that expose events and then call those events are no different to pub-sub services in the SOA world. Essentially calling events in C# like is a "service" calling a method on one of its dependants "client". When we built pub-sub services in WCF, callbacks to clients were always done asynchronously (preventing a client from possibly blocking the service) and any faults resulting from communication or unhandled client side exceptions were isolated, again to protect the service from its clients.

Why is it not the practice in .NET to also fire events asychronously and to always handle (and swallow???) exceptions in event handlers? In my experience code where an event caller depends on the success of a handler is poor design...you should be calling methods for things you depend on. Surely an object exposing an event doesnt not care either how long the handlers take to do their work...or if they even succeed?

Discuss!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually there are many design considerations to be made when designing a language. Now i can think of a some concrete arguments for implementing events the way it currently is:

First of all, the simplicity. Implementing a fire and forget system makes it almost impossible to implement, as a coder, a fire and react system. However, implementing a fire and react system makes it easily possible to implement a fire and forget system. Next to that, events are very straight forward. Events are just multicast delegates where only the declaring class can fire them. Nothing more, nothing less.

Secondly, some code in the .NET core framework rely on the event system in conjuction with a fire and react system. For example the Winforms BeforeExit event which has the possibily to cancel in the event Arguments.